# How to show buttons like parallelly in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to show the buttons in parallelly view like showing the below image. How to align buttons in parallelly in flutter for android application. But I do not know how to align it. I have attached images for more info. If anyone knows the answer please help to find the solution.

```
       child: SingleChildScrollView(

          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 510,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 300, // <-- Your width
                  height: 50, // <-- Your height
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      //validateForm();
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => const PhoneLoginScreen()));
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color(0xff557de3),
                        shape: StadiumBorder()

                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      "SIGN IN WITH",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 13,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 300, // <-- Your width
                  height: 50, // <-- Your height

                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      onGoogleSignIn(context);
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color(0xFF557de3),
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                      //primary: Color(0xFFF5F1F1),
                    ),

                    child: const Text(
                      "GMAIL",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 13,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),

                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 300, // <-- Your width
                  height: 50, // <-- Your height

                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      onGoogleSignIn(context);
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color(0xFF557de3),
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                      //primary: Color(0xFFF5F1F1),
                    ),

                    child: const Text(
                      "PHONE",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 13,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),

                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

        )
```

From my code:

[image]

Expecting like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would probably switch to a `Wrap` widget considering your expectation.
[See Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)

Main differences are:

- Add infinite width to the first widget, so it always takes all the space available.
- Removed width on the others. I don't see the need for a 300 width. I might have missed something.
- Handle spacing directly with the Wrap widget properties

```
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Wrap(
            alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
            runSpacing: 20.0, // Or more
            spacing: 20, // Or more
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity, // <-- Your width
                height: 50, // <-- Your height
                child: // Button
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50, // <-- Your height
                child: // Button
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50, // <-- Your height
                child: // Button
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

[image: result]

Comment: How to set width for sign in with button?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Row` widget for this inside the `Column` widget.

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    EmailButton(),
    PhoneButton(),
  ],
),
```